# how to display selected value of dropdown in input text fields in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

html file:

```
<select ng-model="shipping" ng-options="shipping.shipping for shipping in shipAddress">
 <option value=''>--Select Address --</option>
</select>

<form name="shippingForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
    <p class="control-p col-sm-2" for="Address">Address Line1</p>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address Line1"
         ng-model="shipping.addressLine1" class="input-width" ng-init ="shipping.addressLine1"/>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
      <p class="control-p col-sm-2" for="Address2">Address Line2:</p>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" name="AddressLine" placeholder="Address Line2" ng-model="shipping.addressLine2" class="input-width" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

js file:

```
if (data){  
          console.log(data);      
          $scope.addressToShip = data; 
          var ShipAddress=[];
          storeLocally.set('ship Info', data);
          if(data.addressLine2 == null){
            $scope.shipAddress = data.map(function(address) {
                  return {
                  shipping: address.addressLine1 
                  };

               });
           }
          else{
          $scope.shipAddress = data.map(function(address) {
              return {
              shipping: address.addressLine1 +', '+ address.addressLine2
              };

           });
      } 
      }
 },
    function (data) {
        //if (data.status == 500) {
        //  $scope.addressError = "Oops! No Address Found!";    
        };
```

data:

```
{0 :"123 waller st,suite#220"},
{1 :"323 waller st,suite#230"}
```

The problem is the form I am using intially to save data. Once data is saved to db it is coming in dropdown. After choosing one value from dropdown it should come to text fields.

I have tried so far ng-model by using same variable names,even though form's  ng-model and dropdown's ng-model have same variable i.e. shipping.. But it didn't work. Please help me out what I am missing in here.

Comment: A bit confused what is the ask here... It would be more helpful if you give out a clearer flow.    "once data is saved to db", does that data come from user posting the form? If you can describe the task better I don't think it's a hard problem.

Comment: Try to change the `ng-model` of the `select` element to something like `shipping.addressLine1`

Comment: @ShawnXu It means the form is saving data to db. then I call a service which shows same data in dropdown. Now I choose one element of dropdown then it should populate to form text fields.

Comment: @MoshFeu i didnot understand your point.Can you please give me more elaboration.

Comment: I'm trying to answer you. Hopefully that I understand you correctly..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal and you data's schema, you need to change the `ng-model` of the `input[name="Address"]` to `shipping.addressLine1.shipping`.

I get this idea according the data's structure that came from the `.map`:

```
return {
     shipping: address.addressLine1 
};
```

You can see the structure when you pick a option from the `select` - the model will displayd and you can see that the structure is (for example):

```
{
  "addressLine1": {
    "shipping": "123 waller st"
  }
}
```

If you have a question about this, let me know.

I tried to simulate the situation without the server, hopefully I simulate it right.

**Now, to the code:**

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var data = [{
    addressLine1:"123 waller st", addressLine2:"suite#220"
  }];

  if (data) {
    console.log(data);      
    $scope.addressToShip = data; 
    var ShipAddress = [];
    //storeLocally.set('ship Info', data);
    if (data.addressLine2 == null) {
      $scope.shipAddress = data.map(function(address) {
        return {
          shipping: address.addressLine1 
        };
      });
    }
    else {
      $scope.shipAddress = data.map(function(address) {
        return {
          shipping: address.addressLine1 +', '+ address.addressLine2
        };
      });
    } 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="shipping.addressLine1" ng-options="shipping.shipping for shipping in shipAddress">
    <option value=''>--Select Address --</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <pre>
    {{shipping | json}}<br />
    {{shipping.addressLine1 | json}}
  </pre>
  <form name="shippingForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <p class="control-p col-sm-2" for="Address">Address Line1</p>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address Line1"
               ng-model="shipping.addressLine1.shipping" class="input-width" ng-init ="shipping.addressLine1"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <p class="control-p col-sm-2" for="Address2">Address Line2:</p>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="AddressLine" placeholder="Address Line2" ng-model="shipping.addressLine2" class="input-width" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: actaully my value in dropdown is "445 margrita st,suite#220". If I am trying your code It is not showing anything in addressLine1 text field.

Comment: Why not? Here is a picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hLbog.jpg. Also if you want that value, put it in the `map` when you create the models to the dropdown.

Comment: No You didnt get me o/p in dropdown has values like this: { {"445 margrita st,suite#220"},{"442 waller st,suite#110"}  } so 445 margrita has index:0 and 442 waller has index : 1....'data' is object but shipping :address.addressLine1 is creating string and pushing it to array shipAddress. So dropdown is showing array having string i.e."445 margrita st,suite#220"

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe it will be better if you will create a snippet or something so I will understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using AngularJS' `ng-change` attribute in the drop down?

Try like this:

```
<select ng-model="shipping" ng-options="shipping.shipping for shipping in shipAddress" ng-change="someFunction(shipping.shipping)">
  <option value=''>--Select Address--</option>
</select>
```

In your controller add the following function:

```
$scope.someFunction = function(shipping) {
  $scope.shipping.addressLine1 = // Assign value from the shipping variable here
  $scope.shipping.addressLine2 = // Assign value from the shipping variable here
}
```

Hope this helps!

Here is a working jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ashishU/umn8or3g/1/